# Using GLMM/GAM to predict species abundance based on environmental variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm, generalized-additive-model

I hope someone out here can help me. I have some species sighting data and some associated environmental variables, looking something similar to this (a few more enviro variables):

```
| Date      | Shark_Sightings|Salinity| SST  | Protected_Area |Bathymetry  |Tide |DistanceToShore_m|
|:---------:|:--------------:|:------:|:----:|:--------------:|:----------:|:---:|:----------------:
| 01/06/2016| 1              |36.13   |21.85 | PNNM           |2           |R    |20
| 28/08/2015| 1              |36.24   |26.75 | Outside        |-45         |H    |37
| 25/10/2015| 0              |35.05   |23.76 | RMCV           |-98         |L    |103
```

I'm essentially looking to model species abundance and to understand whether it is influenced by any of the environmental variables, and if so which ones. The Salinity & SST values are monthly, bathymetry is standard 2020 GEBCO, Tide is daily data, and distance to shore is just based on nearness to the island's coast. Protected_Area is whether the shark was seen inside the boundary of a marine PA or outside.

I'm currently working in R, so I was initially thinking GLMM or GAM - but for some reason none of my model outputs are significant, and I'm getting confused about family, and actual structuring of the formula. I'm a novice so I'm unsure whether it's my data, or it's me...

I've tried a couple of different options, which I'll show you here:

```
form <- Shark_Sightings ~ Protected_Area + Tide + Salinity + DistanceToShore_m
SharkModel <- glm(form, data=BoatLandWater, family=poisson)

SharkGAM <- gam(Shark_Sightings ~ Protected_Area + s(SST, k=30) + s(Salinity, k=30),
                data = BoatLandWater, method = 'REML')
```

Are there any obvious mistakes I am making or tips on how to create a good model? Or good resources that can help - I've looked at a few and managed to follow along but my data is not producing the same results.

I would also appreciate any tips on how to plot these sort of results nicely.

Thank you in advance.